# Animated Timing No Duration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation

While I was playing around with the Animated component that react-native provides, I noticed that the `Animated.timing();` the function was really powerful, but it ends after a specific set duration. I.E `duration: 2000,`. Duration is useful and all but what if I needed a `Animated.Value();` to constantly increment? Obviously, duration can't be used, and I want to find out how to increment a `Animated.Value()` not based on duration, but incremented instead by an integer like say 2 endlessly? Also, I want to use the `useNativeDriver: true,` as well as it makes my animation less laggy.

How would I do this? I'm grateful for any suggestion/solution! Thanks for reading!

Comment: Indeed a baffling question. If you want a dynamic duration for your animation you can save it in a variable and increase it every time. Just in constructor write this.animationDuration = 500; and increase it whenever you want.

Comment: @DNA.h Hey, i see where you're coming from. Let's say i have a value let number = 0. then i were to increment it by 2. so number += 2. Do you know how to do such if the number were an Animated.Value() instead? Keep in mind i still want to use the useNativeDriver: true, config somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every animation has three values. a)starting value, b)ending value and c)duration. I tested them myself to be sure and it seems you can change them dynamically **between** every run, and by the way you can use useNativeDriver: true too (also tested myself). Here is a template of what i did.

```
    export class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.duration = 500;
        this.scale = 1.5;
        this.startScale = 1;
        this.animScale = new Animated.Value();
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Animated.View style={{height: 500}}
               transform: [{scale: this.animScale}>
               <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
                    this.animScale.setValue(this.startScale);
                    Animated.timing(
                        this.animScale,{
                            toValue: this.scale,
                            duration: this.duration,
                            useNativeDriver: true
                        }
                    ).start();
                    this.scale += 0.2;
                    this.startScale += 0.1;
                    this.duration += 100;
               }}>
                    <Text>let's go</Text>
               </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </Animated.View>
        )
    }
}
```